# How can I specify what part of a word doc to display when embedded

Tags: microsoft-word, ole

When I embed sub.docx in main.docx, is there a way to have only part of sub.docx display in main.docx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In sub.docx, select the chunk of text that you want to appear in main.docx, and then, on the **Insert** tab, in the **Links** group, click **Bookmark**. Make a note of the bookmark name that you enter, because you'll have to manually enter it again in step 2.
2. In main.docx, place the cursor where you want the embedded content to appear, as usual, and then use one of these methods:

   - On the **Insert** tab, in the **Text** group, click **Object** > **Text from File**. Select sub.docx, click **Range**, and then enter the name of the bookmark that you inserted. Click the arrow on the right side of the **Insert** button, and then click **Insert as Link**.
   - On the **Insert** tab, in the **Text** group, click **Quick Parts** > **Field**. In the **Field names** list, select **Include text**, and then click **Field Codes**. After `INCLUDETEXT`, type the file name (`sub.docx`) and then the name of the bookmark that you inserted.
   - Manually add the field by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. Between the braces (`{}`), type `INCLUDETEXT`, followed by the file name and then the bookmark name.

   In both the second and third methods, enclose the file name in quotation marks if it contains spaces, and enter the full path of the file if it's in a different directory than main.docx.

   For example, sub.docx is in the same directory as main.docx, and I want to insert the section that contains the results of benchmark testing. In sub.docx, I have added a bookmark named BenchmarkResults around the relevant text. In this case, my field code will look like this:

   > `{ INCLUDETEXT sub.docx BenchmarkResults }`

If you want to include the bookmarked text as static (non-updatable) text in main.docx, use the first method under step 2, but instead of clicking the arrow next to **Insert** and then clicking **Insert as Link**, just click **Insert**.